# MVVM Light Nuget installation on VS2105

Tags: mvvm-light

I am installing the MVVM Light Nuget package into a new blank app (Universal Windows) project.  I was expecting the viewmodellocator.cs file to be created along with others, but this did not happen and I was wondering if there is a solution for this?

I am using VS2015 Enterprise edition.

Thanks